# AppFabric advantages over normal SqlWorkflowInstanceStore

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I know that AppFabric gives possibility to efficiently track and store workflows.
Anyway, for pure persistence, there is also the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore (which, I guess, is used by AppFabric).
I would like to understand which are the advantages of using AppFabric instead of simple SqlWorkflowInstanceStore and which is the overhead of this choice.

Thanks,

Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are interested in is persistence go with the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore. Windows Server Appfabric adds management and tracking capabilities to that. But Appfabric is a plugin for IIS so only works for workflow services.

Answer (score 0):

Appfabric includes several services which enable the restarting of workflows (if your using xamlx via WorkflowServiceHost).   You need to perform most of the management techniques of not only starting but restarting a workflow was was terminated in mid stream by something like a server dying.

I found that appfabric really required me to explicily host my workflows using WorkflowServiceHost to be able to correctly use automated management methods that appfabirc exceled at

[MSDN - AppFabric Persistence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677272(v=azure.10).aspx)

If you arent using XAMLX (or WorkflowServiceHost) and instead using the WorkflowApplication to host your workflows then I couldn't find a good way to truly utiliize appfabnric and then that mean just using the WorkflowInstanceStore instead

[MSDN - WorkflowInstanceStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee383994(v=vs.110).aspx)